# Machine Compatibility Test

Tags: hypervisor

We currently have a server running VMware server 1.0X. I'm trying to get it ready to install ESXi. I'm running the compatibility test on the go.vmware.com site and I'm getting a failure.

Number of processors does not meet the minimum requirements (2).

Listed below is the configuration for the machine.

```
OS Name Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition
Version 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 3790
Other OS Description R2
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name BLACK
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
System Model PowerEdge 2950
System Type x64-based PC
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
Processor EM64T Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2993 Mhz
BIOS Version/Date Dell Inc. 2.6.1, 4/20/2009
SMBIOS Version 2.5
Windows Directory C:\WINDOWS
System Directory C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710)"
User Name CHERNAY\Administrator
Time Zone Eastern Standard Time
Total Physical Memory 12,282.64 MB
Available Physical Memory 7.25 GB
Total Virtual Memory 13.48 GB
Available Virtual Memory 10.76 GB
Page File Space 2.00 GB
Page File C:\pagefile.sys
```

The machine has Intel Xeon DP 5050 CPUs.

Am I missing soemthing here? Souldn't this pass the test.

Thanks.

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xeon 50xx-series based Dell 2950's aren't supported with ESXi v4.

The 52xx, 53xx and 54xx are however.

Comment: I believe you can still get a 3.x version of ESXi that will run on these hosts

Comment: @Chopper3 fo you know offhand why the 50xx chips aren't supported? I remembered they weren't but couldn't find the reason.

Comment: I don't know what technical function must be missing but no Netburst-based chips appear to be supported with v4. ESXi.

Comment: Where did you find that?  The HCL I found here ( http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=search&deviceCategory=server&productId=1&advancedORbasic=advanced&maxDisplayRows=50&key=&release%5B%5D=34&datePosted=-1&partnerId%5B%5D=-1&formFactorId%5B%5D=-1&cpuSeriesId%5B%5D=17&filterByEVC=0&filterByFT=0&min_sockets=&min_cores=&min_memory=&rorre=0 ) doesn't show that?

Comment: hmm, the Dells *are* listed for ESXi 4.0U1 installable  --  Might be worth a "try it and see"...